# Is it possible to set the auth cookie in BeginRequest?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working with a client that can read, but not send cookies. This is a problem since the client is to post to authenticated methods. I figured an easy work around would be to send the cookie information in a header, intercepting it in BeginRequest and attaching a fabricated cookie to the request. Since begin request occurs before Authentication I figured it would work. It did not.

Here is my current method.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        // I have added the auth cookie to the header
        var a = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (a == null) return;
        // get cookie value
        var s = a.Replace(".AspNet.ApplicationCookie=", "");
        // I am injecting the cookie into the request
        var c = new HttpCookie(".AspNet.ApplicationCookie", s);
        Request.Cookies.Add(c);
    }
```

I have set breakpoints to observed the "real" cookie and it matches my "fabricated" cookie.  Am I doing something wrong or am I trying for the impossible ? Moreover if anyone has any Idea how I could authorize the user using the cookie information I would be great-full.

This is a MVC5 application using the now standard Owins library.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using cookies in the first place?  If the client can't handle them well, why not use JWT - OAuth tokens?

Answer (score 0):

The Owins framework is called on before BeginRequest. Moreover, the Owins request context is read only. So yes, adding to the cookie is impossible using Owins.

... But it is possible to create your own owins middleware that reads the header value and 'unprotects' the AuthenticationTicket. The solution is based off the [Cookie Middleware](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationMiddleware.cs).